# Why the property Size of UIImage is half of the real picture size?

Tags: ios, uiimage, size

I have a picture named `pic` of 268*381,
I have defined

```
UIImage* tempImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic"];
```

But when I print

```
NSStringFromCGSize(tempImg.size)
```

it shows `{134, 190.5}`

I can't understand the principle of this, and I would be very grateful the solver!

Comment: Are you running on a Retina (2x) device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for `UIImage size`:

> In iOS 4.0 and later, this value reflects the logical size of the image and is measured in points

Remember that pixels is equal to points times scale. Or points is pixels divided by scale.

Your `268x381` size is in pixels. The output of `NSStringFromCGSize(tempImg.size)` is in points. A result of `{134, 190.5}` means this is an image with a scale of 2. Most likely you have this image as `pic@2x.png`.